# How can I get wireless extensions?

Tags: command-line, wifi, kali-linux, vmware, aircrack-ng

When I type this command `iwconfig` in Kali Linux when I am root the output is

```
lo   no wireless extensions
eth0  no wireless extensions
```

Comment: You have no wireless network interface. `lo` is loopback, `eth0` is Ethernet.

Comment: @berndbausch okay... how can I get network interface?

Comment: You have a network interface, but it's wired. You can buy Wifi interfaces everywhere, for example [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wifi+usb&ref=nb_sb_noss_1).

Comment: Do you run your Kali in VM?

Comment: Kali has a page for [troubleshooting wireless network drivers](https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-wireless-driver-issues/). The first paragraph is named "No Interface". It may contain useful information for you, if you think your computer has a WiFi interface.

Comment: @JiriB yes i do

Comment: You will need to pass your wireless interface on your host into the VM. If you have an USB wireless adapter then you can pass the USB interface into VM. If you have a PCI wireless device then you need to do PCI pass-through via IOMMU/VT-d. What virtualization do you use?

Comment: @JiriB i use vmware

Answer (score 0):

PCI-Passthrough is not possible in VMware, you have to use a USB Wi-Fi adapter.